# how to solve babel dependencies?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

ERROR in ./ClientApp/Client.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):

## Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions.

```
{
  "name": "misreact",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "path": "^0.12.7",
  "main": "HelloWorld.js",
  "dependencies": {
     "@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
     "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
     "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
     "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
     "react": "^16.6.0",
     "react-dom": "^16.6.0",
     "webpack": "^4.23.1",
     "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
   },
  "devDependencies": {
     "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
     "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
     "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.10"
   },
  "scripts": {
     "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
     "start:dev": "webpack-dev-server --hot"
   },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
 }
```

Comment: For `Babel 7` you need to install `@babel/env` and `@babel/preset-react`

Comment: post your babel config.

Comment: run: 
`npm install babel-loader @babel/core @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react`
add to: ".babelrc"-file
`{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ]
}` , cheers!

Comment: forget to add and StackOverflow dosen't allow to modify answer. Remember to use `--dev`-flag when installing these compiler stuff since you DO NOT want them in your final bundle.

Comment: @JimiPajala tried your suggestion, but came with below error:
ERROR in ./ClientApp/Client.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions. In C:\Users\ARMAN\xautopilotdev\misreact\node_modules\babel-preset-stage-2\lib\index.js

Answer (score 0):

As of Babel 7, stages are deprecated. You can use the following package to update automatically (the following command will run the update with installing babel-update on your computer permanently):

```
npx babel-upgrade --write
```

This package is going to install all stage-2 updates (each updates is an individual package now). You may want to consider what updates you actually need and remove the rest.

I would upgrade to @babel/env and @babel/preset-react as well, as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: ERROR in ./ClientApp/Client.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions. In ~\node_modules\babel-preset-react\lib\index.js    at createDescriptor ~\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:178:11)
    at items.map ~\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:109:50)

Comment: at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at createDescriptors ~\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:109:29)
    at createPresetDescriptors ~\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:101:10)
    at passPerPreset ~\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:58:96)
    at cachedFunction ~\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\caching.js:33:19)
    at presets.presets ~\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:29:84)

Comment: at mergeChainOpts ~\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-chain.js:315:26)
    at ~\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-chain.js:278:7
    at buildRootChain ~\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-chain.js:68:29)
    at loadPrivatePartialConfig ~\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\partial.js:85:55)
    at Object.loadPartialConfig ~\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\partial.js:110:18)    at Object.<anonymous> ~\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:140:26)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)

Comment: at asyncGeneratorStep ~\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:3:103)
    at _next ~\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:5:194)
    at ~\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:5:364
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (~\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:5:97)
    at Object._loader (~\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:220:18)
    at Object.loader (~\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:56:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (~\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:51:12)

Comment: It looks like you didn’t upgrade to @babel/preset-react. Did yo run the command I posted above? Please do not just post error messages. It’s not very helpful. Could you post your .babelrc file?

Comment: yes, I run the command you posted. But no luck. Above error messages produced after I ran your command.

Comment: {
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
      {
        "legacy": true
      }
    ],
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-constant-elements",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-inline-elements",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings",

Comment: [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
      {
        "legacy": true
      }
    ],
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-sent",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-logical-assignment-operators",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining",
    [

Comment: "@babel/plugin-proposal-pipeline-operator",
      {
        "proposal": "minimal"
      }
    ],
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-do-expressions",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-bind"
  ]
}

Comment: above is the .babelrc file contents